# Change Boolean from another component in angular 4

Tags: angular

I'm using `Booleans` and a `userRights.service` for checking whether a nav-point is shown or hidden. So therefore i'd like to check the rights from the user who's logging in, and than set the variables for the navigation to `true` or `false`.

I have two components for that: My `navbar.component.ts` and my `login.component.ts`. Inside my `navbar.component.ts` are Booleans (15) like this ->

```
canAddHardware
canChangeUserRights
canEditBlog
...
```

So now the user logs in, inside my `login.component.ts` and the `onLogin()` function gets triggerd. I'm calling my `userRights.service.userHasRight('canAddHardware')` for example, and than i need the `Boolean` inside my `navbar.component.ts` to be the value which gets returned from my `userRights.service.userHasRight('canAddHardware')` -> true or false

I tried so many things but i'm not able to figure out how to do this.

Comment: What's the relationship between these components?

Comment: have you tried     <can-add-hardware-element     *ngIf="userRights.serivice.userHasRight('canAddHardware')>.  If necessary you could have a function in your nav-bar component which calls the user rights service and returns the value rather than trying to reach out to it from the template

Comment: I already did that like you said Farasi. I implemented my service as condition onto my nav-menu-points but the problem is, that the service gets triggerd many times when the user clicks a link. I have about 15 - 18 menu points and every change the service is triggerd a hundred times and everything gets so damn slow. Thats why i need another solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this components are not siblings than you can create a message service like this:

```
export class ShareDataService {
messageSource = new BehaviorSubject<IMessage>({
    messageType: 'message',
    payload: 'something',
});
currentMessage: Observable<IMessage> = this.messageSource.asObservable();
changeMessage(message: IMessage) {
    this.messageSource.next(message);
}
```

}

Then from your login.component.ts you can then dispatch a message using a method like the below:

```
    sendMessage(message: MessageType, data: any) {
    const messageToSend: IMessage = {
        messageType: message,
        payload: data,
    };
    this.shareDataService.send(messageToSend);
}
```

And in your navbar.component.ts you can listen to that message in the ngOnInit for example:

```
        this.shareDataService.currentMessage.subscribe((message: IMessage) => {
          if (message === 'message') {
              this.canAddHardware = true;
          }
        });
```

Comment: and how would i do this for all of my menu points? How would i add another menu point inside your example?

Comment: Not sure if I understand - this solution is a general one on how to communicate between components which are not siblings. You emit a message whenever you want - in a method - and pass as payload whatever data you want. Then from the listening component you can access the payload and trigger logic accordingly.