# How do I call a function from another component

Tags: angular, angular5

I would like to call a function from another component.

To describe it in more detail, I have a module with 3-4 different components inside them. One of them is sidebar, the sidebar contain labels with links to other components.  One of those linked components contains a table that can be sorted by 3/4 different functions.

Previously I manually wrote the code of sidebar  within the component that had tables for this code to work.

My main component contains left and right column, the left column never changes and it contains one outside component and a side bar, the right column changes.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="leftCol">
        <info></info>
        <sidebar></sidebar>
    </div>
    <div class="rightCol">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```

Within my sidebar, I made a label like this :

```
 <label [routerLink]="['/users']" (click)="sortByName('all'); currSort='abc'">ABC</label>
```

What I want to achieve when I press this label is to open up /users, which works but it does not execute the command sortByName which is located in users component.

```
sortByName(str) {
    this.users = [];
    let token = localStorage.getItem('feathers-jwt');
    this.userService.getUsers(token).subscribe(res => {
      let users = res.data.sort((a, b) => {
        if (a.lastname.toLowerCase() < b.lastname.toLowerCase()) return -1;
        if (a.lastname.toLowerCase() > b.lastname.toLowerCase()) return 1;
        return 0;
      });
      for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        let char = users[i].lastname.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
        if (str == 'all' || char == str.toUpperCase()) {
          let object = { name: char, array: [] }
          for (let j = 0; j < users.length; j++) {
            if (char == users[j].lastname.charAt(0).toUpperCase()) {
              object.array.push(users[j]);
              users.splice(j, 1);
              j = -1;
            }
          }
          i = -1;
          this.users.push(object);
        }
      }
      this.clicks = 0;
    }, err => {
      this.toast.error('Loading users', 'FAILED')
    })
  }
```

Putting this function in sidebar component.ts did not do the trick either.

What do I have to do in order for sidebar label to open up linked website and also execute function on click?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `sortByName` _should_ be a function in the sidebar's component

Comment: this is what I was thinking as well, and I have placed it there but unfortunately I still do get an error that the function softbyname is not a function. And If I put it back in users component and copy the label in users.. and I click it, it sorts everything as it should be.

Comment: can you share your code in stackblitz

Comment: If you want to do some operation on parent component. please emit events from child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a sorting-rule-parameter to your routerlink (keyword: paramMap)
Then the user-displaying component could contain the sorting function or better a sorting service is called depending on the given params.
https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5#extract-the-id-route-parameter
Components should only contain fields and methods they really need / use.
Everything else should be extrected to different components, modules and (shared) services

Answer (score 0):

If these are not siblings: [Change Boolean from another component in angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50137379/change-boolean-from-another-component-in-angular-4/50138250#50138250)

If you want to access a child component method: [How to call sibling component method in angular 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50408989/how-to-call-sibling-component-method-in-angular-4/50409469#50409469)

Comment: tried the chield component method, compiles successfully, doesn't sort anything and does not provide any errors in console as well.

Comment: Where is the data to sort located? In the child or parent component?